# SSL error "ssl_error_bad_cert_domain" after moving Magento

Tags: sql, magento, ssl

I changed my Magento directory today. I ran these commands through phpMyAdmin before transfering files:

```
UPDATE core_config_data SET value = 'http://www.yourdomain.com/'
WHERE path = 'web/unsecure/base_url';

UPDATE core_config_data SET value = 'https://www.yourdomain.com/'
WHERE path = 'web/secure/base_url';
```

After that I cleared cache and session folders under var, everything seemed to work OK, but I'm getting error when trying to checkout

> (Error code: ssl_error_bad_cert_domain)

How can I fix that?

Comment: Do you get the error when going to checkout or within a single step at the checkout progress? You can try to track every http/ajax call by using the `httpfox` extension for Mozilla Firefox for example. Then you can see, which URL is called by the script. Maybe the tracelog would be helpful or an URL. In general httpfox will help you to find the exact file which cause the error ...

Comment: This is where Firefox is giving me the error /checkout/onepage/. Alright I'm going to try httpfox, thank you!

Comment: That means, the error occurs if you just go to the checkout? And NOT between step 3 and step 4 for example ...?

Comment: Yes. Same thing happens when I try to go to backend. Alright I got httpfox and I found the error, but don't know what to make of it? Or wich part should I copy here?

Comment: Just a screenshot of the requested urls (httpfox view). Maybe we can see a rough mistake ...

Comment: Alright I added a screenshot of httpfox window to my original post.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, I got it figured out. The certificate was for "mysite.com", but in Magento under System - Configurations - Web - Secure I had put "https://www.mysite.com/" so after I changed it to "https://mysite.com/" it works fine.